# Select rows from CSV based on a list of IDs

Tags: c#, linq, csv, full-text-search

I have a task of extracting a few hundred thousand rows from CSV files where the row contains a specified ID. So I have about 300,000 IDs stored in a string List and need to extract any row in the CSV that contains any of these IDs.
At the minute I am using a Linq statement to see if each row contains any of the IDs in the List:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile))
{             
    string inLine = sr.ReadLine();
    if(searchStrings.Any(sr.ReadLine().Contains))
    {
         stremWriter.Write(inLine);
    }
}
```

This kind of works ok but it is Very slow since there are 300,000 values in the searchStrings List and a few million rows in the CSVs that I need to search.

Does anyone know how to make this search more efficient to speed it up?
Or an alternative method for extracting the required rows?

Thanks

Comment: How static is the data? A couple of indexed SQLite database tables and an IN/JOIN query would be one way.

Comment: The data is updated quarterly but the CSVs actually contain data that is from a relational data model but the ID is in the same location which is why I'm just doing the string search rather than loading it into a data base. 
So each CSV could contain multiple different record types that have the same ID, it is the main link between all of the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similarish problem before, I had to iterate through a several hundred thousand line .csv and parse each row.

I went with a threaded approach where I tried to do the reading and parsing simultaneously in batches.
Here's **roughly** how I did it;

```
    using System.Collections.Concurrent; using System.Threading;
    private static ConcurrentBag<String> items = new ConcurrentBag<String>();
    private static List<String> searchStrings;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile))
        {
            const int buffer_size = 10000;
            string[] buffer = new string[buffer_size];

            int count = 0;
            String line = null;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer[count] = line;
                count++;
                if (count == buffer_size)
                {
                    new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            find(buffer);
                        }).Start();

                    buffer = new String[buffer_size];
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                find(buffer);
            }

            //some kind of sync here, can be done with a bool - make sure all the threads have finished executing
            foreach (var str in searchStrings)
                streamWriter.write(str);
        }
    }

    private static void find(string[] buffer)
    {
        //do your search algorithm on the array of strings
       //add to the concurrentbag if they match
    }
```

I just quickly threw this code together from what I remember doing before so it might not be entirely correct. Doing it like this certainly speeds things up though (with very large files at least).

The idea is to always be reading from the hdd as string parsing can be pretty expensive, and thus batching the work on multiple cores can make it significantly faster.

With this, I was able to parse (splitting each line into about 50 items and parsing the key/value pairs and building objects in memory from them - by far the most time consuming part) around 250k lines in just over 7s.

Comment: I didn't think of using threading so thanks for the very useful example, this has helped cut down the process quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there, it's not specifically relevant to any of the tags on your question but the *nix "grep -f" functionality would work here.  Essentially, you'd have a file with the list of strings you want to match (e.g., StringsToFind.txt) and you'd have your csv input file (e.g., input.csv) and the following command would output the matching lines to output.csv

`grep -f StringsToFind.txt input.csv > output.csv`

See [grep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for more details.